# Why does not variance add in general?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, statistics, random-variables, variance

Can someone explain why does not variance add in general? Like this:
$$Var(X+Y) ≠ Var(X)+Var(Y)$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because the formula for variance does not let you add it. While Expectation ($E[X]$) is linear, this does not mean that variance is.

$$
Var(X) = E[X^2] - E[X]^2 
$$
which is clearly not linear, since

$$
Var(X + Y) = E[(X + Y)^2] - (E[X + Y])^2 \\
= E[X^2 + 2XY + Y^2] - (E[X] + E[Y])^2 \\
= E[X^2] + 2E[XY] + E[Y^2] - E[X]^2 - E[Y]^2 - 2E[X]E[Y]
$$

while

$$
Var(X) + Var(Y) = E[X^2]- E[X]^2 + E[Y^2] - E[Y]^2
$$

Comment: Isn't this true? Var(X)=E[X^2]−E[X]^2

Comment: Yes, that is what I wrote.

Comment: he meant that doesn't mean the variance is linear.

Comment: got it!............

Answer (score 6):

As a simple counterexample, take $Y=-X$.

Then

$$Var(X-X) \ne Var(X)+Var(-X).$$

---

The property holds only when the variables are uncorrelated.

Comment: The property holds when they are *uncorrelated*, which is quite a bit weaker than being independent.

Comment: Changed to uncorrelated.

Answer (score 1):

\begin{align}
Var(X+Y) &= Cov(X+Y, X+Y) \\
&= Cov(X,X)+Cov(X,Y)+Cov(Y,X)+Cov(Y,Y) \\
&= Var(X)+ Var(Y)+2 Cov(X,Y)
\end{align}

In general, convariance between $X$ and $Y$ need not be $0$.

Comment: Anyway to do this without using covariance? I did not learn that.

Comment: I see. What is the definition of variance that you are familiar with? did the other answers clear your doubt?

Comment: Var(X)=E[X^2]−(E[X])^2

Comment: I believe Siddharth's answer should suit you. =)

Comment: @VadaCurry FYI: Covariance of $X, Y$ is similarly defined: $$\mathsf {Cov}(X,Y)~=~ \mathsf E(XY)-\mathsf E(X)\mathsf E(Y)~=~\mathsf E\big( (X-\mathsf E(X))(Y-\mathsf E(Y)\big)$$ PS: The property Siong Thye Goh used above is known as the *Bilinearity of Covariance*.

Answer (score 0):

The general formula is
$$\text{Var}(X+Y) = \text{Var}(X) + \text{Var}(Y) + 2 \text{Cov}(X,Y),$$
so the equality in your question fails precisely when $\text{Cov}(X,Y) \ne 0$.

Comment: Anyway to do this without using covariance? I did not learn that.

Comment: @VadaCurry See Siddharth's answer. In his answer, the difference between $\text{Var}(X+Y)$ and $\text{Var}(X) + \text{Var}(Y)$ is $2E[XY] - 2 E[X] E[X]$, which is precisely $2 \text{Cov}(X,Y)$.

Answer (score 0):

Roughly speaking, the variance represents the second moment of a PDF, this means that its behavior is nonlinear (quadratic) on the variables, that is why

$$
E(X + Y) = E(X) + E(Y)
$$

but

$$
{\rm Var}(X + Y) = {\rm Var}(X) + {\rm Var}(Y) + 2{\rm Cov}(X, Y) \not= {\rm Var}(X) + {\rm Var}(Y)
$$